# Custom Action in Designer for While Loop

Tags: workflow-activity

How to implement Custom action for While Loop useful in Designer..
Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide more details on what you're trying to do - The 'Custom action' for 'while loop' is a bit vague..

Comment: I am implementing custom action e.g. While field __ equals InActive Call Workflow. I want to execute the activity in a Loop continously till the condition is false.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Sharepoint SP2 removed the loops within workflows, as it was unfortunately pretty easy to create infinite loops.

See: [Service Pack 2 prevents an on-change workflow from starting itself](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2009/07/13/service-pack-2-prevents-an-on-change-workflow-from-starting-itself.aspx)

If you scroll towards the bottom, you will also get an idea of how to create a similar while loop - The issue is that you have to keep track of 2 different workflows, dealing with 2 custom list. Bascially one triggers another one, creating the effect of a 'continuous' loop.